# Can you inspect the flutter focus tree?

Tags: flutter, focus

Is it possible to inspect an app's focus tree the same way the flutter devtools let you inspect the widget tree? I'm currently trying to learn about focus and the app's focus tree and visualization may help.

I feel like I don't have a way to know what is currently in focus while I'm troubleshooting.

Comment: `print(FousManager.instance.toStringDeep());`

Comment: I think that is a good start but it is basically a printout of the FocusNode's ancestors. I'm looking for something that shows the entire tree and not just the ancestors of the node that is in focus.

Comment: it shows both ancestors and siblings

Comment: basically it (recursively) shows all the children that are returned by this method: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/DiagnosticableTreeMixin/debugDescribeChildren.html

Comment: Ah, gotcha. My problem is I don't know enough about the focus tree that I can tell the difference yet. I will use this to learn more about the tree. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing `debugDumpFocusTree();`

TIP: In order to find your way across the focus tree. You can try adding debug labels. like this

```
FocusNode(debugLabel: "mentionable")
```

Comment: That works pretty nicely. Thanks.